Why does unplugging my laptop increase GPU power consumption?
Setting
I've been benchmarking a graphics task.
When my laptop is plugged in, starting the task leads to a moderate increase in GPU power consumption and usage percentage moderately, but it doesn't push the GPU frequency above its minimum level.
When my laptop is unplugged, starting the task leads to a large increase in GPU power consumption and usage percentage, and it pushes the GPU frequency from minimum to nearly maximum.
Question
Why does unplugging my laptop make the GPU draw more power and cycle faster?
I can see why a low-power mode might increase the GPU usage percentage: the GPU has less resources, so it has to use a larger percentage of them to accomplish the same task.
However, increasing the GPU's frequency and power consumption seems like a weird thing for a low-power mode to do.
Details
I'm measuring GPU resource usage with AMDGPU_TOP. The graphics hardware and driver details in the list below are also reported by AMDGPU_TOP.
Quantitative behavior differences
Laptop plugged in, task running

Average GPU power: 9 W
Graphics pipeline usage: 50–60%
GPU serial clock rate: 800 MHz

Laptop unplugged, task running

Average GPU power: 14–18 W
Graphics pipeline usage: 75–90%
GPU serial clock rate: 2224 MHz

System information

Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04
Desktop environment: GNOME 42.9
Window manager: Wayland
Graphics card: AMD Radeon 780M
OpenGL driver: Mesa 24.2.0 (kisak-mesa PPA)
GPU clock frequency: 800-2700 MHz
Supported GPU power profiles: [empty list]


This is a hardware question and based on what you have written here I see noting Ubuntu related.

@DavidDE, this is a question about power management and the amdgpu kernel module, as my tags indicate. I'm under the impression that power management details can be distribution-specific. Why do you see this as a hardware question?

@DavidDE: In the past, another Ask Ubuntu question about GPU power management turned out to be related to an Ubuntu bug (which has now been moved to the Kiwi Linux issue tracker; I'm not sure why).
